# Getting maximum Key Values in Map

Tags: hashmap

How do I get maximum key values in a Map and let's say save it to a List?

For example, is there is a Map:
John, 30
Alexander, 10
Ivan, 20
Steven, 30

The result must be a List: John, Steven

Comment: Users on StackOverflow will help you, **after you help yourself**.  Take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  Do some research: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527.
Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  And what language is this in?  Edit your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional List...

```
Double max = 0d;

for (String key : wagesList.keySet()) {
    if (wagesList.get(key) > max) {
        max = wagesList.get(key);
    }
}

for (String key : wagesList.keySet()) {
    if (wagesList.get(key).equals(max)) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```